# Java hexadecimal converter ignores the first digit

Tags: java, unicode, hex

I have a character unicode value in decimal (capital A is 65).

When going higher in values, for example 120016 is a mathematical A, I have to retrieve the character based on it's value in decimal.

To achieve that, I used

```
char c = (char)key;
```

I encounter a very strange behavior : the first hexadecimal digit is ignored.

Here is a screenshot from NetBeans.

Here is the unicode value of the character I want to print

[image]

120016 converted in Hex is 1D4D0.
However, when it is converted by the code above, it is converted as \uD4D0, as you can see, the first Hex digit is ignored.

[image]

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening. 
There is no instruction inbetween those two statements, the key value is only given as a parameter, so it cannot have been changed by the time it is converted in hex.

Comment: char in Java is equivalent to a 2 byte int. So you could never have a char with hex value 120016 as that is out of bounds

Comment: An int is 32 bits and can hold 8 hex digits. A char is 16 bit and can only hold 4 hex digits.  Typecasting int to char silently discards the rest.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers. What should I use then ? String will not convert the unicode value to an unicode character, because you cannot do `String s = "\u" + code`. So what should I do ?

Comment: 'I have a character Unicode value in decimal' and 'the first hexadecimal digit' are mutually contradictory. The reality is that you have a binary value, not decimal or hexadecimal digits. Unclear what you're asking. Don't post pictures of text here. Complete waste of your time and our bandwidth.

Comment: Thank you, you are very kind !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen explained, casting an int to a char silently discards bytes consumed by an int (4 bytes) that exceeds the limits of the char type(2 bytes).

To bypass this limitation, don't make the conversion to a char but to a String.
You can use the `Integer.toHexString(int)` method that
returns a string representation of the integer argument as an unsigned integer in base 16.

```
int x =  120016;
String string = Integer.toHexString(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Mathematical A is 120016 **in utf-8** Java uses **utf-16** , so that is why you're seeing a different value- it is different encoding

Answer (score 0):

a `int` spend 32 bits, a `char` spend 16 bits and a hex digit spend 4 bits.
when cast a `int` to a `char`, the bits that overflowed will be truncated. for example:

```
int key = 0b00000000000000011101010011010000;//120016
                            ^---------------
char c  =                 0b1101010011010000;// (c = (char)key) == 0xD4D0
```